# Create a patch to add a kubernetes annotation

Tags: go, kubernetes, webhooks, patch

I would like to write an [mutating webhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/#mutatingadmissionwebhook) to add a default ingress class to all ingress object, that do not explicitly provide one.

According to the [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/test/images/webhook/addlabel.go#L29) I found I need to provide a proper json patch for the webhook to return.

I first tried my patches using kubectl:

```
$ kubectl patch ingress mying --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations/key", "value":"value"}]'
The  "" is invalid
```

Looks like this is not working when there is not already an annotations element present.

```
$ kubectl patch ingress mying --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations", "value":{"key":"value"}}]'
ingress.extensions/kafka-monitoring-topics-ui patched
```

Creating the complete annotations element works fine, however in my case I need a key of `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` which contains a slash.

```
kubectl patch ingress mying --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations", "value":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"value"}}]'
ingress.extensions/kafka-monitoring-topics-ui patched
```

This works fine when creating the annotation object. However, if there is already a some annotation present and I simply want to *add* one, it seems to be impossible to add one.

Simply using `[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations", "value":{"kubernetes.io/ingress.class":"value"}}]` removes all existing annotation, while something like `'[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations/kubernetes.io/ingress.class", "value": "value"}]` does not work because of the contained slash.

**Long story short: What is the correct way to simply add a ingress class using a proper patch?**

PS: Yes, I am aware of `kubectl annotate`, but unfortunately that does not help with my webhook.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Replace the forward slash (`/`) in `kubernetes.io/ingress.class` with `~1`.

Your command should look like this,

```
$ kubectl patch ingress mying --type='json' -p='[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations/kubernetes.io~1ingress.class", "value":"nginx"}]'
```

Reference:
RFC 6901 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901#section-3

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks a lot! I was not aware of JSON Pointers, yet. Adding the class this way will probably only work if the annotation object is already present. - Seems like I have to handle both cases separately.

Answer (score 37):

much easier for me was to `annotate` rather than `patch`:

```
kubectl annotate ingress mying kubernetes.io/ingress.class=value
```

add `--dry-run -o yaml` flags if you want to test it before applying the change.

Comment: `kubectl annotate` is nice utility. But please note that OP explicitly mentioned that they are aware of this and it's not working for their use case

Comment: yeah but it was relevant for a few other people here

Answer (score 6):

Using just:

```
[{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/annotations/kubernetes.io~1ingress.class", "value":"nginx"}]
```

does not work when the created pod has no annotations, for example when coming from `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 --attach test-deploy --image=busybox ls`

To detect this you need a separate parsing step into a metadata with pointer annotation so it can be detected as nil, or always send an empty annotation when it's empty:

```
type Metadata struct {
    Annotations  *map[string]string
}

type ObjectWithMeta struct {
    Metadata Metadata
}
```

then send:

```
[
  {"op":"add","path":"/metadata/annotations","value":{}},
  {"op":"add","path":"/metadata/annotations/foo","value": "bar"}
]
```

Comment: Thank you - this really helped me today. The error message from the Kube API server is totally unhelpful when I was trying to add an annotation and the annotations key was missing.